# How do the public 21 BP's nodes prevent DDOS attacks?

Tags: bp, ddos

There are 21 BP nodes, how do they prevent DDOS attacks that knock them offline by sending massive amounts of traffic to these public ips?

Answer (score 3):

We hope they are paid well, perhaps when the EOS toke price picks up like 10x, to maintain high-end DDOS mitigation infrastructure.

Assuming geographic redundancy and cloud-level diversity, it is possible to have a very strong resistance towards massive DDOS attacks.  However, if most of our BPs are concentrated on AWS or Google Cloud or God forbid the Microsoft one (sorry could not resist), then your concerns are extremely valid.

Having geographic data-center redundancy, ASN number ownership, and a bunch of hackers on the staff would be a good starting point for many of the BPs.

Comment: The question also is: can the replacement of attacked/down BPs with stand-by BPs or votes work seamless if the network is under attack. That's also why bare metal should be used instead of cloud providers running the EOS.IO software...